# Implicitly importing a dependent file

Tags: ruby, import, sass

I have a method that takes a scss file `f` and compiles it:

```
def compile f
  options = ...
  Sass::Engine.new(File.read(f), options).render
end
```

where `options` is a hash that specifies several parameters. All the scss files that I want to compile with this command `@import`-s a fixed file, say `"_foo.scss"`. So at the moment, I have the line

```
@import "foo";
```

at the top of every scss file. I want to let the method above implicitly/automatically do the equivalent to `@import "foo";` so that I do not have to write that at the top of every scss file. How can I do that? Is there something I can do with `options`, or some hack with sass internals?

Comment: Since you're reading the file into memory anyway, you could just do `File.read('foo.scss')` and concatenate it with the contents of `f`.

Comment: @millimoose That would ruin the file and line number information returned from sass when a compile error occurs.